# DataPager losing data after paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ef-code-first

I have a `DataPager` that I use to page through my search results. My DataPager loses its results after i have clicked and paged though some of them, for example if I page 2-3 times i will get just labels like ID and no data.

**Markup**:

```
 <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="LVCAdmin">
     <!-- Templates here -->
 </asp:ListView>

<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" PagedControlID="LVCAdmin" runat="server">

     <Fields>
         <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" 
         ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False"
         ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />

         <asp:NumericPagerField />

         <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button"
             ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False"
             ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
      </Fields>

</asp:DataPager>
```

**CodeBehind**:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string keyword = txtSearch.Text.Trim();

    List<dynamic> Cresults = AdminSearchAll(keyword);

    if (Cresults.Count != 0)
    {    
        LVCAdmin.DataSource = Cresults;
        LVCAdmin.DataBind();

        NoResults.Visible = false;
        LVCAdmin.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        NoResults.Visible = true;

        LVCAdmin.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I added a `OnPreRender="Pager_PreRender"` to my DataPager control. Below is the method. So far it has worked as intended.

```
 protected void Pager_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                   string keyword = txtSearch.Text.Trim();


                    List<dynamic> Cresults = AdminSearchAll(keyword);


                    if (Cresults.Count != 0)
                    {

                        LVCAdmin.DataSource = Cresults;
                        LVCAdmin.DataBind();

                        NoResults.Visible = false;
                        LVCAdmin.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        NoResults.Visible = true;

                        LVCAdmin.Visible = false;


                    }

                }

        }
```